# If statement condition error missing value in two sum problem?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement, indexing

I am working through practice problems for interviews and ran into a problem with an "if" statement that I do not know how to solve. The practice question is as follows:

Two sum. Given an array and a number N, return True if there are numbers A, B in the array such that A + B = N. Otherwise, return False.

Example:

[1, 2, 3, 4], 5 ⇒ True

[3, 4, 6], 6 ⇒ False

My code (below) returns the following error: **Error in if (i + A[j] == N) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

```
fun = function(A,N) {
  flag = FALSE
  for (i in A) {
    for (j in i:length(A)) {
      if (i + A[j] == N) {
        flag = TRUE
      } 
    }
  }
  return(flag)
}

fun(as.integer(c(3, 4, 6)),6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is your second `for` loop should be `1:length(A)` not `i:length(A)`.

```
fun <- function(A, N){
  flag = FALSE
  for (i in A) {
    for (j in 1:length(A)) {
      if (i + A[j] == N) {
        flag = TRUE
      } 
    }
  }
  
  return(flag)
}

fun(as.integer(c(3, 4, 6)), 6)
[1] TRUE
```

When `i` equals `4` and `length(A)` is fixed at 3 your posted code was sequencing `4:3`. `j` will take on a value of `4` and then when you try to index `A[4]` you will get `NA`.

---

**Update**

To avoid double counting an element with your code you could do this:

```
fun <- function(A, N){
  flag = FALSE
  for (i in A) {
    for (j in A[A != i]) { # select elements of A that aren't equal to i
      if (i + j == N) {
        flag = TRUE
      } 
    }
  }
  
  return(flag)
}
```

Though this isn't super efficient because it will double check some pairs twice.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I had that was to not double count pairs; any comments on why i:length(A) doesn't work? Also, the output should be false, not true (see example).

Comment: You're welcome. I mentioned in my original answer why `i:length(A)` doesn't work. I've updated my answer so that this function does not sum the same element.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I came up with the following: ```fun = function(A,N) {
  m=length(A)
  flag = FALSE
  for (i in 1:m) {
    for (j in i:m) {
      if (A[i] + A[j] == N & i != j) {
        flag = TRUE
      } 
    }
  }
  return(flag)
}
```

Comment: Good job! Keep learning. I would recommend studying the answer from @Waldi because many problems in `R` can be solved without `for` loops. Vectorization is a powerful tool.

Answer (score 3):

A vectorized solution without loops:

```
sumN <- function(A,N){
  any(colSums(combn(A,2))==N)
}

sumN(c(1,2,3,4),5)
[1] TRUE

sumN(c(3,4,6),6)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Clean! It took me a while to understand, but I learned a lot! I tried to upvote, but my reputation is not good enough yet. I hope this will do for now:  ^

Comment: Nice you took time to understand : whenever you can, vectorize instead of looping - much more efficient!